# Why Spring MVC can instantiate Abstract class?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, abstract-class

Probably it's a stupid question. In java we can't instantiate abstract classes. So we can't do:
`AbstractClass abstractClass = new AbstractClass()
abstractClass.method();`

But in Spring we can do:

```
@Autowired
AbstractClass abstractClass;
abstractClass.method();
```

Why?

Comment: Just name is not enough for a class to be abstract. Check it would be a concrete class or it might be using Runtime polymorphism.

Comment: That's just coding to the interface. Spring will find a concrete class that matches. Same as if you said `@Autowired List x`. This ends up being an ArrayList or a LinkedList or some other List.

Comment: And you can do that without using Spring too: `AbstractClass abstractClass = new ConcreteClass()` where `ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring will search in its context for an implementation that match the required type.
So if you have a component (@Component, @Service, @Repository...) ConcretClass that extends from AbstractClass then this one will be injected.